# meteor fullcalendar not reacting to events at all

Tags: events, meteor, fullcalendar

I use drblue:fullcalendar. Display works fine but I cannot get any kind of event to work. I have tried different ones. In the following code snippet I have tried the loading event:

```
Template.Schedule.helpers({
    calendarOptions: {
        // Standard fullcalendar options
        schedulerLicenseKey: 'CC-Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives',
        slotDuration: '01:00:00',
        minTime: '07:00:00',
        maxTime: '22:00:00',
        lang: 'en',
        defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
        contentHeight: 500,
        firstDay: 1,
        timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
        timezone: 'UTC',
        selectable: true,
        // Function providing events reactive computation for fullcalendar plugin
        events: function(start, end, timezone, callback){

            var events = [];

               Assignments.find().map(function(doc){

                    var startTimeHours = Number(doc.time.substr(0, 2));
                    var startTimeMinutes = Number(doc.time.substr(3, 2));

                    var startDateTime = new Date(doc.date);
                    startDateTime.setHours(startDateTime.getHours() + startTimeHours);
                    startDateTime.setMinutes(startDateTime.getMinutes() + startTimeMinutes);

                    var endDateTime = new Date(doc.date);

                    var effort = doc.state == 'finished' ? doc.realEffort : doc.effort;

                    endDateTime.setHours(startDateTime.getHours() + effort);
                    endDateTime.setMinutes(startDateTime.getMinutes());

                    var getColorForState = function(state)
                    {
                        switch(state)
                        {
                            case 'finished': return '#00bb00';
                        }
                        return '#1197C1';
                    };

                    var getBorderColorForState = function(state)
                    {
                        switch(state)
                        {
                            case 'finished': return '#009900';
                        }

                        return '#004781';
                    };

                    return{
                    id: doc.title,
                    start: startDateTime,
                    end: endDateTime,
                    title: doc.title,
                    backgroundColor: getColorForState(doc.state),
                    borderColor: getBorderColorForState(doc.state)
                }
            }).forEach(function(event){

                events.push(event);
            });
callback(events);
        },
        // Optional: id of the calendar
        id: "calendar1",
        // Optional: Additional classes to apply to the calendar
        addedClasses: "col-md-12"
        // Optional: Additional functions to apply after each reactive events computation

     }
    });

Template.Schedule.events({
    loading: function(isLoading, view){
        console.log('hi');
    }

});
```

No JS error on client or server and no log entry, either. I have also tried dayClick, select and clickEvent but I do not get any log entry. If I put an `alert` into it I also do not receive anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why downvoted, if you need more information or details, please provide it.

Anyways, I was able to solve it. There was some "wrong" code out there and I did not find any example, *but* it works when I just add the corresponding event to the options, i.e.:

```
Template.Schedule.helpers({
    calendarOptions: {
        // all the various options
        eventClick: function(event, jsEvent, view){
            alert(event.title + "\r\n\r\n" + event.description);
        },
```